# Apache Commons HttpConnection : PostMethod - Get Underlying HttpConnection

Tags: java, apache, connection

How would I go about getting the underlying HttpConnection of a org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod, or org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient Object?

Comment: Why? HttpConnection is an abstraction of a stream reader, are there any methods avaliable to you to capture an input/output stream?

Comment: @BryanAbrams I'm trying to close stale connections which is possible from HttpConnection but not PostMethod or HttpClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an instance of `HttpClient` you can use this to get a `HttpConnection` reference:

```
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
    // ...
    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();  
    httpclient.getHttpConnectionManager().getConnection(HostConfiguration.ANY_HOST_CONFIGURATION);
    // ...
    httpclient.executeMethod(post);
```